# android list the data from database using recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want display the data's from android database. Here i am using recycler view. The reference code is http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ . My code shown below.

```
SpeedDialViewActivity.java

public class SpeedDialViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Bean> beanList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ViewAdapter mAdapter;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_dial_view);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new ViewAdapter(beanList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    prepareData();
}

private void prepareData() {
    DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Bean> beanList = handler.getAllContacts();
    Bean bean;
   for (Bean cn : beanList) {
        String log = "Id: " + cn.getId() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getNumber();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
       /* bean = new Bean(cn.getName(), cn.getNumber(), cn.getSpeeddial());
        beanList.add(bean);
        }*/




   /* Bean bean = new Bean("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
    beanList.add(bean);

    bean = new Bean("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
    beanList.add(bean);
    bean = new Bean("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
    beanList.add(bean);
    bean = new Bean("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
    beanList.add(bean);*/
}
}
```

In the prepareData() method i can print answer in log. But i cannot display in my activity. Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changed `prepareData()` method by adding `List<Bean> beanList = handler.getAllContacts();`

And i have use `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
private void prepareData() {
    DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Bean> beanList = handler.getAllContacts();
    this.beanList.addAll(beanList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: this is a really unclean way to do what you want. the cursor adapter would be the right way. At the moment I have no time to write an example but later today I try to show you a piece of code.

Comment: Please, explain your code. Code-only answer aren't helpful and could be ignore by users.

Comment: @AxelH i have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the cursoradapter to load data from database and display it with a view holder in your recyclerview.

Comment: Can you write an example.

Comment: How it possible with cutrsor adapter.

Answer (score 0):

To show the data from the database in a list, you can use the [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). Simply by create a Cursor to this, you can let him do the job.

A simple example would be the following :

```
 DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
 SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM person", null);
```

Then, you pass this cursor to the adapter:

```
 ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
 MyCursorAdapter adapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
 lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The complicated part is to implements the CursorAdapter to your need. This is the one that will build the view and read the cursor. `BindView` would be call for each row.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
  public MyCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      super(context, cursor, 0);
  }

  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_cursor, parent, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      TextView txtLastName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLastName);
      TextView txtFirstName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName);

      String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("last_name"));
      String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("first_name"));

      txtLastName.setText(body);
      txtFirstName.setText(String.valueOf(priority));
  }
}
```

Here, you have a small example, you just need to generate the Layout (simply two TextView) to match the cursorAdapter I have writen.

The [source](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) I used to generate this small example. You will found much more information than here.